# Why was this closed as "not a real question"

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm confused as to why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661663/find-all-indices-of-one-javascript-array-inside-another-javascript-array) (about finding all occurrences of one JavaScript array inside another JavaScript array) was closed as "not a real question".

Questions are supposed to be closed for this reason when they are "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical", but as far as I can tell, the question doesn't match any of these descriptions.

What is wrong with my question specifically, and how can I improve it so that it can be re-opened?

Comment: Matt Ball nailed it in the first comment there - your question didn't really show any effort.  You just showed your code with a big hole in it, asking the community to tell you what to fill it with.  You need to show some effort before asking on SO, and most importantly, [show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Suicide is a bit extreme for a few downvotes from the meta crowd.  Just learn and grow :)

Comment: @AdamRackis I posted the code that I'd written so far, and I was mainly trying to figure out an approach that might work. I wasn't sure whether it would be better to use a recursive or iterative approach. Is the amount of effort that I put into this question still considered inadqeuate for some reason?

Comment: +1 because I always +1 users trying to learn how to improve questions instead of just getting frustrated or continuing to post bad ones.  Retagging this as support to reflect this.

Comment: I think the best way to improve the question would be to make an attempt at either an iterative or recursive approach, and when it doesn't work (if it doesn't work) ask about _that_.

Comment: My answer was unpopular so I behoove the downvote-crowd to either 1) reopen the OP's question or 2) post your own answer that explains why it was closed.

Comment: @djechlin: I downvoted it because of your interpretation of "many answers/implementations is bad". It is possible to objectively judge whether an implementation/code solution is good or not, and if it is a bad solution then we also learn something from it.

Comment: The question seems to be removed "for reasons of moderation"...

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad to see you've managed to improve and reopen your question. Not enough questions manage to do that these days!

#### So the tips to remember

- Be concise.
- Stay focused.
- If you have code, post it.
- Tell us what's wrong with it.
- Let us know what you've already tried.
- Use **Markdown** *to your **advantage***.  But **don't** *use* <s>it</s> e`x`ce`s`si`vel`y or [unnecessarily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181209/).

---

You did the right thing coming here to meta to ask for advice. Don't just assume a random bunch of people didn't like your question, always try to improve, and always *always **always*** have a good time :)